# How can I offer a download bundle that doesn't trigger the zip warning on browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, next.js, vercel, supabase-database

My application allows subscribers to download a bundle of video editing templates compressed into a zip file.

Chrome is preventing the download due to security. Is there better way to bundle the files, or a process to get vetted by Google to allow the download?

[image: Download Error]

Answer (score 0):

Starting Chrome 84, mixed content - i.e content linked from a secure sources to a mixed content (zip etc.) is blocked as dangerous - Make sure the zip file is coming from a `https` source

source: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1600480115-Chrome-to-block-mixed-content-downloads-in-version-86

Comment: Thank you for the comeback. 

Yes, I did read that article. Things were working fine prior to that release. 

The thing is, my asset package is indeed coming from a https:// source. And I have verified the site with Google.

Here is an example link: https://pqrzkscozbqtqznkyfsq.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/assets/TestAsset.zip. This one downloads fine. Others don't.

Any ideas what could be triggering the error?

Comment: You should use google webmaster tools and have google crawl your site - after a couple of days it should be fine as they will scan for malicious content - another option would be to proxy the link above so it’s not directly linked to supabase